What's the suggested method for modeling arched openings in a cube?
I'm trying to create something like this:

I've tried creating the arches in a couple ways. I modeled the outlines of the arches and used the Knife Project tool on a cube. That wasn't great. Then I Solidified the shapes so they intersected a cube and used Boolean to remove the arched shapes:

I like where it's going, but I'd like to know if I'm going about this the wrong way. Is there some better technique to produce a similar but cleaner result?

I'd prepare the mesh for one and array it. Yes, the resulting mesh would have more edges/vertices, with the vertical loops between archs and horizontal loops between levels, but you will have full control over triangulation and an easier time beveling.
